# I want select data but it doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a table:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ccu_log` (
  `id` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ccu` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5626 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `ccu_log`
--

INSERT INTO `ccu_log` (`id`, `ccu`, `time`, `date`) VALUES
(1, 0, '22:27:30', '2015-01-08'),
(2, 0, '22:29:01', '2015-01-08'),
(3, 0, '22:30:31', '2015-01-08'),
(4, 0, '22:32:01', '2015-01-08'),
(5, 3, '22:33:31', '2015-01-08'),
(6, 0, '22:35:01', '2015-01-08'),
(7, 4, '22:36:31', '2015-01-08'),
(8, 8, '22:38:01', '2015-01-09'),
(9, 5, '22:39:31', '2015-01-09'),
(10, 1, '22:41:01', '2015-01-09');
```

When I want select data with mysql query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `ccu_log` 
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP("date") = UNIX_TIMESTAMP('09-01-2015')
```

It show all rows from my table. If i user query:

```
SELECT * FROM `ccu_log` where UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) = UNIX_TIMESTAMP('09-01-2015')
```

It doesn't return the expected results.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your dates should be 'yyyy-mm-dd'

Comment: i want format it as '09-01-2015'. What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try like this,

```
 SELECT * FROM `ccu_log` where DATE_FORMAT(date,"%d-%m-%Y") = '09-01-2015';
```

Comment: i want format it as '09-01-2015'. What should i do?

Comment: This query will not work.  date needs to be escaped since its a reserved word

Comment: SELECT * FROM `ccu_log` where DATE_FORMAT(date,"%d-%m-%Y") = '09-01-2015';

Comment: Yes, i have try it but it not work in php with text field value ='09-01-2015'

Answer (score 1):

When the field is already of type `date`, you don't even need to convert to a timestamp for comparison. Just do

```
SELECT * FROM `ccu_log` WHERE `date`='2015-01-09'
```